# Изменить значение импортированной переменной и передать изменённое значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, рефакторинг

### 1. Кратко

См. заголовок.

---

### 2. Цель

Имеется программа, состоящая из модулей. В каждом модуле логируются какие-то действия. При запуске программы показывается имя модуля, выдающего логи.

Это реализовал, но только с повторениями в коде. Вопрос в том, как от них избавиться.

---

### 3. Минимальный рабочий пример

(`os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]` — [**получить имя текущего модуля без расширения**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228618/5951529)).

- [**Онлайн-демонстрация на Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/SashaSO-OneVariableForEachFile).
- `config.py`:

```python
def sasha_function(module_argument):
  print(module_argument)
```

- `first.py`:

```python
import config
import os

module_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]

def first_function(module_argument):
  config.sasha_function(module_name)
```

- `second.py`:

```python
import config
import os

module_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]

def second_function(module_argument):
  config.sasha_function(module_name)
```

- `main.py`:

```python
import os
import config
import first
import second

module_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]

first.first_function(module_name)
second.second_function(module_name)
config.sasha_function(module_name)
```

- Вывод:

```text
first
second
main
```

`sasha_function()` в примере — функция логирования; в каждом модуле реальной программы у меня несколько раз проставлено логирование посредством [**logbook**](http://logbook.pocoo.org/). Каждый раз, когда собираюсь вызвать `sasha_function()`, я должен указать аргумент `module_argument`. Значение этого аргумента всегда и для всех файлов одинаковое — `module_name`, имя текущего модуля (без расширения).

Возможно ли не указывать каждый раз `module_name` при вызове функции (а в идеале не переопределять `module_name` в каждом модуле, ведь её значение определяется одинаково для всех файлов)?

---

### 4. Попытки самостоятельно справиться

Безуспешно пробовал через именованные аргументы, `__name__`, `importlib.reload()`.

#### 4.1. Перезапись переменной

Перечитал главы о модулях «Изучаем Питон» Лутца. Попробовал сделать, как в разделе «[**Инструкция from создает копии, а не ссылки**](https://studfiles.net/preview/5624204/page:160/)».

- [**Онлайн-демонстрация на Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/SashaSO-ChangeAndImportVariable).
- `config.py`:

```python
module_name = '_'

def sasha_function():
  print(module_name)
```

- `first.py`:

```python
import config
import os

config.module_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]

def first_function():
  config.sasha_function()
```

- `second.py`:

```python
import config
import os

config.module_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]

def second_function():
  config.sasha_function()
```

- `main.py`:

```python
import os
import first
import second
import config

config.module_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]

first.first_function()
second.second_function()
print(config.module_name)
```

При запуске каждого модуля в отдельности выведется имя запускаемого модуля. Однако если запустить `main`, вывод будет таким:

```text
main
main
main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `config.py`:

```python
import traceback

def sasha_function():
  print(traceback.extract_stack()[-2].filename)
```

- Получим:

```text
/home/runner/first.py
/home/runner/second.py
main.py
```

Если нужно получить именно имена модулей без полных путей и расширений, можно [**сделать так**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678266/5951529):

- `config.py`:

```python
import os
import traceback

def sasha_function():
  print(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(traceback.extract_stack()[-2].filename))[0])
```

- Вывод:

```text
first
second
main
```

- [**Онлайн-демонстрация на Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/SashaLecron-ChangeAndImportVariable).

Comment: Lecron, проблема тут, что если `traceback.extract_stack()` вывести в переменную (чтобы избежать фрагментов почти идентичного кода), то будет другой список, из которого нельзя извлечь имени модуля. [**Пример**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/SashaLecron-ChangeAndImportVariable-1). Спасибо.

Comment: Естественно. Значение определяется в момент вызова, а не импорта модуля. Если не хотите много писать, определите как вызов функции logger = lambda: Logger(traceback.extract_stack()[-3].filename) (! другой индекс, так как увеличился стек вызовов), а при обращении logger().debug(sasha_argument). Или реализуйте требуемое в потомке класса Logger.

Comment: Lecron, да, то, что нужно, спасибо. Прошу прощения за беспокойство.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ @Lecron:

`first.py` и `second.py`

```
import config

def first_function():
    config.sasha_function()
```

`config.py`

```
import traceback
import os

def sasha_function():
  tup = traceback.extract_stack()[-2]
  name = os.path.basename(tup[0])
  print name.split(".")[0]
```

`main.py`

```
import config
import first
import second

first.first_function()
second.second_function()
config.sasha_function()

# first
# second
# main
```

Comment: В Вашем примере, как и моём из п.3, всё равно приходится указывать аргумент `module_name`. А вопрос о том, как упростить код, чтобы этого можно было бы не делать; см. конец п. 3. Спасибо.

Comment: ну можно обернуть, а не напрямую вызвать будет как для first, second, имя модуля main можно узнать только в нём же

Comment: подправил версию @Lecron (для 2-го), если не будет работать выведите `print tup` гляньте там структуру данных

Comment: Eugene Dennis, тоже [**уже подправил**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/SashaLecron-ChangeAndImportVariable). Спасибо.